# Using conditional operator in template statement

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In this code I'm trying to change `transform` property on an element. When I click on element *one* for the first time everything works -- element translates. When I click it again nothing changes. What am I missing?

```
<div id="one" (click)="two.style.transform = (two.style.transform == 'translate(-100vh)') ? 'translate(0vh)' : 'translate(-100vh)'"></div>   
<div id="two" #two></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why this is  working for first time

- because first time assume `two.style.transform == 'translate(-100vh)'` is FALSE then it will run the condition `translate(-100vh)`

Why this is not working second time

- because Second time condition `two.style.transform == 'translate(-100vh)'` is again FALSE then it will run again same condition `translate(-100vh)` so no effect is showing

For better clerification please run the follwing example

```
<div id="one" (click)="two.style.background = (two.style.background == 'grey') ? 'white' : 'red'">BB</div>   
<div id="two" #two>AA</div>
```

Comment: thank you, good sir! I still can't get it to work. Is there another way of doing this inside template? I mean, toggling from one state to another

Comment: @EugeneEpifanov This might be a little late, but you can always have the conditional resolve to a class using `[ngClass]`.  `<div id="one" [ngClass]="{'translateHeight': isTranslated}">`  and then have a boolean in your component to store the state `isTranslated` and then in your css have the class with the transform `.translateHeight { transform: translate(-100vh); }`